# summarizing many tables in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a task to make a summary table of a few thousand other tables containing thousands of records. The summary table should contain:

1. non redundant list of "records";
2. number of tables containing that "record"
3. names of tables containing that "record"

Example would be:

```
Table_1
nameA
nameB
nameC

Table_2
nameB
nameC
nameD

Table_3
nameC
nameD
nameE
```

Result should be something like this

```
Record_name  Number  Table_names
nameA        1       Table_1
nameB        2       Table_1, Table_2
nameC        3       Table_1, Table_2, Table_3
nameD        2       Table_2, Table_3
nameE        1       Table_3
```

Perhaps it is not to complicated thing to do, but, since I'm quite new to `mysql`, I hope to get some advice and help from you guys!

Comment: A few thousand? Good luck with that !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT  col1 as `Record Number`, 
        COUNT(*) as `Number`, 
        GROUP_CONCAT(_name) as `table name`
FROM
(
    SELECT col1, 'table_1' as _name FROM table_1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT col1, 'table_2' as _name FROM table_2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT col1, 'table_3' as _name FROM table_3
) a
GROUP BY col1
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0c2fe/4)

Comment: accept that as your ans. otherwise this post will be loaded with ans like "old wine in new bottle".

Comment: thanks, that was helpful! didn't know about sqlfiddle - now bookmarked!

Comment: oh, one more thing: if I want to do this for an N number of tables? can I loop through a list of tables or perhaps use regexp? thanks